# Flutter for web: cannot find chrome as a connected device. How to enable chrome as a connected device to start developing on web?

Tags: flutter, flutter-web

I have followed the below steps to upgrade to latest version and still cannot find chrome as a connected device.

[image]

How do I enable chrome as a connected device so that I can start developing for web ?

Comment: maybe because of this? `flutter config -h | grep enable-web`

Comment: Thanks mate. That was the problem.

UPDATE: For others: Chrome as a device is available only on master and dev channels of flutter right now.

Comment: sure, your welcome

Comment: ya same problem in windows, how can i solve it?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

run `flutter config --enable-web` on master or dev channel and then you can see chrome as a target in android studio or `flutter devices`

Update: With flutter 2.0 you can also do it on stable.

Answer (score 2):

run `flutter config --enable-web` on **master or dev or beta channel** and then you can see chrome as a target in android studio or `flutter devices`

P.S: Since the flutter for web is available in beta channel now we can use it in beta channel as well. Once flutter for web is released in stable channel this question becomes irrelevant.

Answer (score 2):

**You need to switch to flutter's master channel**. In Terminal, run the following commands:

1. Switch to flutter channel master

```
    flutter channel master
```

2. Enable web support in Flutter

```
    flutter config --enable-web
```